# selenium webdriver detect UI pop up error messages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have this react application being tested using selenium webdriver.

if my login is wrong, how do i detect the text using selenium webdriver? I am unable to find the code/ figure out how to trap the pop up message . 'authentication failed'

```
@Test
public void failed_login() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\rahul\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32_83\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("field_email"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("field_password"));
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Log In']"));
    
    username.sendKeys("wrongemail@gmail.com");
    password.sendKeys("wrongpassword");
    login.click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    assertEquals(url, "http://testingapp.workspez.com/login");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to verify if `authentication failed` pop up is displayed or not:

```
List<WebElement> popUpElement = driver.findElements(By.id("client-snackbar");
if(popUpElement.size() != 0){
  System.out.println("Pop up is Present "+popUpElement.get(0).getText());
}else{
  System.out.println("Pop up is Absent");
}
```

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("client-snackbar")) != null` That expresion is redundant. If the WebElement is not found it will throws exception. That makes `else` useless

Comment: @KunLun : hey, thanks for pointing out about redundant method. Updated answer by removing the same to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

After you perform `click`, you can use Explicit Wait:

```
try{
    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //10 seconds
    WebElement messageElement = wait.until(
                                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                                        By.xpath("//*[@id = 'client-snackbar']")
                                    )
                                );

    //if reach here, means the error is visible.
    System.out.println(messageElement.getText());

}catch(TimeoutException ignored){ 

    //if trigger timeoutexception
    //that means the element with message is not visible, that means no error

}
```

This will wait 10 seconds for the element to be visible.

If it is not visible, it will throws `TimeoutException` which you can simply ignore.

That means the error was not visible in first 10 seconds after click.

You can change the time with whatever you want.

Comment: for strange reasons, i get 'NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)' error. So i couldn't proceed with this. thanks for helping answer

Comment: `Lcom/google/common/base/Function;` what is that? What exactly you send as parameter to `WebDriverWait.until`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the locator for that toast message.
For locating web element

1. Go to your login.
2. Enter your invalid credentials.
3. Press F12 and go to console/Sources
4. Click on login to get your message.
5. Press F8 to pause it. Now you can inspect your element.

So from webelement you can fetch text with gettext() method.
You can apply explicit wait to wait for your error message.